# MyBatis oracle insert new row always return wrong primary id value

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, mybatis

Try to get the primary id after inserting a new row to oracle DB

```
<insert id="createActivityLog" parameterType="ActivityLog" >
  <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="java.lang.Integer" order="BEFORE">
      select ACTIVITY_LOG_SEQ.nextval as id from dual
  </selectKey>  
  insert into ACTIVITY_LOG (
         activity_log_id,
         notes,
         details            )
  values (
     #{id,jdbcType=NUMERIC},
     #{notes,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
     #{details,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
  )
```

Here is the java call

```
Integer myId=(Integer) activityLogDao.createActivityLog(alog);
```

New data/row can be inserted into DB with no issue with correct primary key/id. But myID is always returned as 1(supposed to be 8971). How can I get the correct value. Thanks in advcance.

version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert returns 1 on success and 0 on failure. If you want to use the primary key, use getId() of the object you used to insert.

Example:

```
// 1 or 0 = success or failure
int result = activityLogDao.createActivityLog(alog);

// get Id, the 'alog' object mapped to the id
Integer myId = alog.getId();
```

Comment: Do you mean along.getId()?, the primary key will  be mapped to parameter object?

Comment: The object mapped to the id of the <selectKey keyProperty="id"> you used in your DAO

Answer (score 0):

As `<selectKey />` requires extra query, `useGeneratedKey` is preferred in general.
I'll show you how to use `useGeneratedKeys` for the following usages.

1. Use `nextval` in insert statement
2. Use `nextval` as the default value of a column
3. Use `identity` column

For explanation, I'll use a separate table for each case.

```sql
create sequence test_seq increment by 1 start with 1;

create table user1 (
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);

create table user2 (
  id int default test_seq.nextval,
  name varchar(10)
);

create table user3 (
  id int generated always as identity,
  name varchar(10)
);
```

Insert statement for usage 1 would look as follows.

```java
@Insert({
  "insert into user1 (id, name)",
    "values (test_seq.nextval, #{name})"})
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true,
  keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
void insert1(User user);
```

Here is an XML version just for the sake of completeness.

```xml
<insert id="insert1" useGeneratedKeys="true"
  keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
  insert into user1 (id, name)
    values (test_seq.nextval, #{name})
</insert>
```

Insert statements for usage 2 and 3 are essentially the same.
Note that `id` is omitted from the column list.

```java
@Insert({"insert into user2 (name) values (#{name})"})
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true,
  keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
void insert2(User user);
```

Here is a demo project:
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-66252438