# Insert and select is returning 1 instead of actual value in mybatis XML way

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have coded the below code snippet, the values are storing in DB is correct but while fetching the carId after inserting its always returning 1 instead of actual value, I can't use order="AFTER" as already I have used one order in generating sequence, and cannot use annotations based way as our org code structure does not allows that. Can someone please identify what I am doing wrong in XML-based way of inserting and fetching data?

Note** - Using oracle DB

```
<insert id = "insertIntoCar" parameterType = "CarEntity" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="carId">
<selectKey keyProperty="carId" resultType="long" order="BEFORE">
SELECT CAR_ID_SEQ.nextval From DUAL
<selectKey>
INSERT INTO CAR (CAR_ID, CAR_TYPE, CAR_STATUS)
VALUES (#{carId}, #{carType}, #{carStatus})
<insert>
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66252438/1261766

Comment: @ave, I have checked that solution but that doesn't work for me because my entity object is not prefilled.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not prefilled'? Please add the code that prepares the entity object and calls the `insertIntoCar` method. Or even better, a complete demo project like the one I linked in my answer.